# drupal gmap node location as static image, not interactive map

Tags: google-maps, drupal-7

I am worried my site may go beyond the google maps usage allocation (is it 2500 hits/month?) I wanted to replace some of the smaller maps I load on my website with static ones. Presently I use the GMap location block to display the node's location in the sidebar. Does anyone know of a simple workaround which will allow me to use static maps instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use custom blocks with php/html codes, this should work perfectly for you + blocks can be cached in drupal.

Comment: awesome - ok - working part-way - this is a good opportunity for me to learn about variables and how to access them for the different fields of different content types. Is there an easy way to output and browse field names without returning the entire content array? I'm specifically looking for the lat/long now.